# R: How to fill in NA Values within a Column based on grouping?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to replace the NA values in this example data frame with either 'A' or 'B' depending on their 'second' column category: (A for A1, B for B1)

```
df <- data.frame(first = c("A","A",NA,NA,"B",NA,NA,NA),second = c(rep("A1",4),rep("B1",4)))
df
  first second
1     A     A1
2     A     A1
3  <NA>     A1
4  <NA>     A1
5     B     B1
6  <NA>     B1
7  <NA>     B1
8  <NA>     B1
```

This is what I would like the resulting data frame to look like:

```
  first second
1     A     A1
2     A     A1
3     A     A1
4     A     A1
5     B     B1
6     B     B1
7     B     B1
8     B     B1
```

I tried this solution but obviously it didn't work:

```
df$first[is.na(df$first)] <- unique(df[!is.na(df$first),"first"])
```

I have a feeling there might be a dplyr solution but cannot think of it.

Thank you!

Comment: `df$first[is.na(df$first)] = strsub(df$second[is.na(df$first)], 1, 1)`

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate of question 23340150. The aim here is to replace NA based on the value of a second column, not the most recent non-NA of the same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `dplyr`. This should work in base R:

```
df$first[is.na(df$first)] <- gsub("(\\w)\\d", "\\1", df$second[is.na(df$first)])
```

Explanation: Here, `gsub` replaces NA entries in `first` with entries from `second`, by matching [letter][digit] from `second` and replacing with [letter].

```
  first second
1     A     A1
2     A     A1
3     A     A1
4     A     A1
5     B     B1
6     B     B1
7     B     B1
8     B     B1
```

Comment: I believe best practice is to avoid regular expressions when possible.

Comment: I disagree. Given that `second` is a string, regexp is the way to go. It allows for way more flexibility than substring extractions based on coordinates...